# "Failed to add new printer" while trying to add network (CUPS) printer on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, cups-lpd

I am trying to add a CUPS printer via settings/printers. After clicking "Add..." the printer isn't listed until hostname is given. Then selecting the printer  results in this error: "Failed to add new printer.". I don't know how to investigate this.

Printer is configured on a raspberry pi CUPS service and test works fine on the device. However, I can't add the printer to the system.
Any ideas?

Edit: Printer is a Samsung ML-1860. I have the driver and PPD files to print via USB both on the server and Ubuntu. Problem is to make the network part work at the moment. I am not sure, what the network print protocol is implemented here. I have it simply on CUPS on the server side and "shared". I can access it via URL/browser. e.g. http(s)://:631/printers/Samsung_ML-1860

Both are in the same local home network/subnet.

Comment: Details needed. Which printer model? Which network printer protocol?  Do printer and computer share same subnet?

Comment: @N0rbert added details. I have done the basic investigation on networking, access etc.

Answer (score 2):

I met **the same problem** today. I have a server A, and a printer, and a Linux machine B, and some Windows machines C,D,... On Windows, I just follow [this](https://sspai.com/post/40997), it worked well. But when I try to add the printer for my Linux machine B (following **the same steps with you**), it just showed me 'Failed to add new printer'. (Ubuntu 20.04)

I don't know whether you have solved it, but I just solved it and am willing to share my solution, hope can help you :-)

My solution:
use **command line** instead of GUI. Run this on my machine.

```
sudo lpadmin -p LaserJet -E -v http://192.168.1.9:631/printers/HPPrinter
```

`lpadmin` is a tool specific for CUPS printer setting up. you can search for Google for more detailed usage.

In my command above, `LaserJet` is the name you want to assign the printer, and the address after `-v` is your address of printer. Mine is just for example, you should modify it according to yourself.

After running this in terminal, the printer showed up in [Settings]->[Printers].

In the end, I find it always a good choise to **use command-line if you meet any problem in GUI operation.** Because command-line will, if operation not successful, give you more detailed error log or sth like that. :-)
This is also why I prefer Linux instead of Windows when programming and developing my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the user to `ldadmin` group by running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo adduser <username> lpadmin
```

where `<username>` is the username of the account you want to enable adding network printers on.

Reference: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1640815#c1

Comment: The user is already part of the `lpadmin` group.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line Murphy's answer worked great for me once i realised

```
https://
```

needs to be replaced with

```
ipp://
```